# how to log phase of NWC Australia 19.8KHz in a file in python

Tags: digital-communications, python, phase, array-signal-processing

First I am very new in this field,and i am doing a college project and i stuck at determining phase of msk signal which is transmitted from a radio stations called NWC Australia 19.8Khz , so let me give you some background,
i am building a software like UltraMSK like or spectrum Lab like which is basically do two things log amplitude and phase of a signal,we have build an antenna and a amplifier circuit and we feed the data to a soundcard and process it in python currently my script logs the amplitude perfectly we have compared it with other available resources on the internet,now we stuck in phase part,

if we log the phase of the signal for a full day and then plot that data next day we should get this type of graph, currently phase part is not working,

[image]

in our code we do FFT of the signal in chunks and for the phase part as i know i do arctan(y/x) of the complex result returned from FFT

`phi=np.angle(fft, deg=True)`

on the above code i do np.angle full FFT then i just filter out our NWC frequency

```
nwc=np.where((fftTime>19790)&(fftTime<19810))[0]
print(phi[nwc])
```

please help me